# Angularjs ngModel directives in input controls

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to angularjs and besides working on a project using angularjs I'm learning it as well. The query which I have, is relevant to the following code:-

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Name:<input ng-model="name" type="text"/>
    <br>
    Name:<input ng-model="name" type="text"/>
    <br>
    Name:<input ng-model="name" type="text"/>
    <br>
    Hello {{name}}
  </body>
</html>
```

In this code, there are `ngModel` directives with every input control and when I type in any one of the input control the value of other two input controls also update. I know `ngModel` directive binds input, select and textarea with property and changes in any of the control are detected in {{expression}} observing directive. But here I didn't see any {{expression}} observing directive in input controls. So, how the values in input controls are updated.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: see, http://ngtutorial.com/learn/scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  tried your code, it works in plunker. The "Hello ..." gets updated per character I type : http://plnkr.co/edit/U9IpmKNALfpAqNNhoTHa?p=preview

```
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular.js Example</title>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  Name:
  <input ng-model="name" type="text" />
  <br>Name:
  <input ng-model="name" type="text" />
  <br>Name:
  <input ng-model="name" type="text" />
  <br>Hello {{name}}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah it works but i want to make this thing clear that how input control values change/update without any {{expression}} observing directive in them

Comment: ng-model is 2-way binding, that's why it updates... {{ }} is one-way binding, equivalent to ng-bind

Comment: Can you please give a precise example code that clears 2-way binding? Also, i read this 2-way binding in official docs but code can clear more

Comment: Your code already shows that. 2-way binding means things get updated via model to view, OR view to model. In your case, when you edit the first input control ("view"), behind the scenes, $scope.name (model) gets updated. Which results in updating the second and third input controls (from model to 2 views)

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks alpinescrambler :)